# From Last day get error in dio client in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dio

I called api request and it worked fine, i used dio client and get data properly. but since last day it dosen't work!. i tried to solve this problem. it shows thousand of line in Logcat. but what is the actual problem? any solution?

[image: this is the problem that shows in emulator]

**This is dio api response**

```
Future<List<ListAlbum>> listData() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
  String url =
      'https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getOrganizationData?token=${token}';
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  final body = {'limit': 10, 'orderBy': 'idEmployee', 'orderType': 'DESC'};
  final response = await dio.post(url, data: body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.data);
    return response.data["data"]["data"]
        .map<ListAlbum>((json) => ListAlbum.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed!');
  }
}
```

**Full Code here**

```
class OrganizationList extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrganizationList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrganizationListState createState() => _OrganizationListState();
}

class _OrganizationListState extends State<OrganizationList> {
  late Future<List<ListAlbum>> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = listData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<ListAlbum>>(
          future: futureAlbum,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final ListAlbum item = snapshot.data![index];
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Text(item.idEmployee!.toString()),
                    title: Text(item.fullName!),
                    subtitle: Text(item.officeID!),
                    trailing: Text(item.designation!),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => DetailsListOrganizationData()),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('${snapshot.hasError}');
            }
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListAlbum {
  final int? idEmployee;
  final String? avatar;
  final String? fullName;
  final String? officeID;
  final String? email;
  final String? designation;
  final String? department;
  final String? mobileNumber;
  final String? workStation;
  final String? businessUnit;

  ListAlbum({
    this.idEmployee,
    this.avatar,
    this.fullName,
    this.officeID,
    this.email,
    this.designation,
    this.department,
    this.mobileNumber,
    this.workStation,
    this.businessUnit,
  });

  factory ListAlbum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ListAlbum(
      idEmployee: json['idEmployee'],
      avatar: json['avatar'],
      fullName: json['fullName'],
      officeID: json['officeID'],
      email: json['email'],
      designation: json['designation'],
      department: json['department'],
      mobileNumber: json['mobileNumber'],
      workStation: json['workStation'],
      businessUnit: json['businessUnit'],
    );
  }
}
```

so, i think dio client have some problem. but not sure!

Comment: It seems to be and backend error

Comment: are you sure? what kind of backend error is this?

Comment: I think is an sql error, check your backend and try to call form Postman

Comment: but it works fine in postman. i mean, when i call this in postman. data show properly!